# Is P2Pool vulnerable to pool hopping?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, p2pool, pool-payout-methods, pool-hopping

Some pools / payout mechanisms are vulnerable to [pool hopping](https://bitcoil.co.il/pool_analysis.pdf).

Is [P2Pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool) vulnerable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Wiki on P2Pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool#Payout_logic):

> Each share contains a generation transaction that pays out to the previous n shares, where n is the number of shares whose total work is equal to 3 times the average work required to solve a block, or 17280, whichever is smaller. Payouts are weighted based on the amount of work each share took to solve - proportional to the p2pool difficulty at that time.

So it works like a PPLNS pool, which is not vulnerable to pool hopping.